# Z-index of two tables not working properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, z-index

I have one table that has an unknown number of columns and rows (jQuery fills that in later). I need to make sure that the column headers stick to the top of the page so when a users scrolls away, they don't get lost. I tried very many different approaches to sticking the headers to the top, and the following is the only one that worked.

So I built a second table above it that contains only the column headers. Then I moved it down to be above the column headers of the original table. This way the user can scroll away and make it seem like the column heads are staying there. I had this working in bootstrap 2. Then I migrated to bootstrap 3 and now the z-index isn't working.

Basically what happens now is that the top table that is supposed to be overlapping the bottom table is actually the one that is going underneath instead. I have played with the z-index a bunch of everything, but nothing seems to be working. It always goes underneath instead of above.

Here is my html.

```
    <!--ResultSet table columns only TOP TABLE-->
<div class="row tableScroll" id="resultsColumns" >
    <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped table-bordered" id="ResultSetTableColumns">
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<!-- ResultSetTable BOTTOM TABLE-->
<div class="row tableScroll" id="results">
    <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped table-bordered" id="ResultSetTable">
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And my css

```
    #results{
        overflow: auto;
        max-height: 440px;
        margin-left:.1em;
        z-index: -1000;
    }
    #resultsColumns{
        overflow:hidden; 
        margin-left:0.1em; 
        z-index: 8000;
    }
    #ResultSetTable{
        z-index: -1000;
    }
    #ResultSetTableColumns{
        margin-bottom: -2em;
        z-index: 8000;
    }
```

Or maybe you guys know a better way of making the bottom tables headers disappear without altering the row widths?

Thanks!

Comment: Do these elements have a `position` value different from the default value `static`? (Only then a z-index can work.)

Comment: nowhere do I have a position set for these elements. They reside in a class="row" of bootstrap together as siblings. And sorry I don't understand from your comment, I need a position to be static for z-index to work? Or I cannot have position: static?

Comment: The latter – z-index applies to positioned elements only.

Comment: ok I'll try and add that now and see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: Ok that seems to have done the trick! Thank you very much!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give these elements have a `position` value different from the default value `static`.

Only then a z-index can work – [it applies to positioned elements only](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index).